# Why the CCLabelBMFont can't start a new line wih "\n"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Like This:

```
    CCLabelBMFont *label=[CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"Text"] fntFile:@"BasicFont.fnt"];
    [label setScale:[[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"Scale"]floatValue]];
    [label setPosition:ccp(objectPosition.x,objectPosition.y)];
    [self addChild:label];
```

I tried to load text from a plist file.
The text in the plist file is "Hello \n World"

It displays the same ("Hello \n World").

However, if I replace **[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"Text"]** with **"Hello \n World"**, it displays in two lines.

I also changed "\n" into **"/\n" or "\n"**, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"Text"]` with:

```
[NSString stringWithString:[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"Text"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In cocos2d v2.0 you can break the line with \n. In my project I am simply using like

```
CCLabelBMFont *lblBonus = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BONUS \n %d",bonusScore] fntFile:@"myCustom.fnt"];
lblBonus.position = ccp(.....);
[self addChild:lblBonus];
```

To do content alignment there are few posts in cocos2d forum. Currently I dont remember the direct link to the posts. But sure you will get it by searching for multiline. I knew someone (may be Mark) has done nice work but that was for older version of cocos2d.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help
dictionary doesn't understand and reads it as a literal  “n”, and not as character ‘n’.

I'm sure there is a better way to get the text break to work
But you could try this...

```
NSString *Text = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
NSArray  *strings = [Text componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
if ([strings count] >= 2)
Text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@n%@",[strings objectAtIndex:0],[strings       objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Youll Get line breaks by adding a bottom underscore to your text (this is how the lines are being broken up using componentsSeparatedByString:@"_")

For instance your text in the dictionary should be something like this

Word_Words on other line_and now another line.

I haven't tested it but hope it helps put you on the right track :)